# Assignment priority of variables in java

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

I have a code snippet example

```
int i1 = 2;
int i2 = 3;
int i3 = i2 + (i2 = i1);
```

Please can anyone explain to me why `i3` will be initialized with 5 in this case? I thought that `i2` after `(i2 = i1)` will be 2. And `i2 + i2` will be 4

Comment: `i2` is set to 2 midway through the expression. First it's 3, then it's 2.

Comment: Left-to-right evaluation is still the rule, and assignment happens whenever it's encountered in that order.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thank you a lot! Now it's clear `int i3 = (i2 = i1) + i2` will give 4. Bytecode gave more understanding

Answer (score 3):

You are making the common error of confusing operator priority with order of evaluation of operands.

Priority affects the structure (i.e., meaning) of the expression only. Since you use explicit parentheses, there's no real doubt in `i2 + (i2 = i1)` -- it can't possibly mean `(i2 + i2) = i1`.

HOWEVER, in Java, evaluation of operands is always [left-to-right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7). So `i2 + (i2 = i1)' means:

1. Take value of i2, call it 'tmp1'
2. Take address of i2, call it 'tmp2'
3. Take value of i1
4. Store a copy of that value at address 'tmp2'
5. Add the value in hand to the value of 'tmp1'
6. which is the result of the expression

This sequence is didactic only, I do not mean this is the actual object code produced by the compiler. But it is how to understand what result you'll get.

In practice, though, you don't want to be writing code that's combining assignments to a variable and using the prior value of the variable. If I were doing the code review, I'd advise you to reformulate.

Comment: There is only a single operand on the RHS.  More precise working than mine: [*The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

Comment: You ought to be able to infer it: in `i2 + (i2 = i1)` the **operation** of assignment to i2 has to happen before the addition of the prior value of i2 and the result of the assignment,  Compare `i2 + i3 * i4` - I assume it's self-evident that the multiplication has to occur before the addition, but nevertheless, that is "evaluation from left to right". The JLS is naturally a little stricter in its descriptions. However, I will now include the word 'operand' in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Much better. We should always be careful with the word “always”.